# what is wrong in my program ? i am trying to find the list of prime number from n to m

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program to find the prime numbers from n to m, but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

For example, if I enter in 2 for n and 9 for m, I just get back

```
2
```

when the correct output should be

```
2
3
5
7
```

Here's my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintStream output = System.out;

    output.print("Enter a number to test: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int m = input.nextInt();
    boolean isPrime = true;
    int i = 2;
    while (n > 0 && n < m)
    {
        isPrime &= n % i != 0;

        if (isPrime)
        {
            output.println(n);
        }

        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see a prime find algorithm here

Comment: I am trying to see if other can do my homework for me

Comment: If you don't know what's wrong, what makes you think anything is wrong with it?

Comment: when i input 2 and 9 program shows the output 2 but it should show the output 2 3 5 7

Comment: thanx  nikhilk  forcoding but i want to know what is problem in my coding it checks the number is prime why it is  not  increment the value of n

Comment: I see two problems at a glance: 1) You're `&`ing the results of each value of `n` together (why would whether or not `n` being prime affect whether `n+1` is prime?) 2) You're also never incrementing `i`, so that divisibility test only ever checks divisibility by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it my way. Hope this helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class PrimeNumbers
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {        
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      int i =0;
      int num =0;
      //Empty String
      String  primeNumbers = "";
      System.out.println("Enter the value of n:");
      int n = scanner.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter the value of m:");
      int m = scanner.nextInt();

      for (i = n; i <= m; i++)         
      {                   
         int counter=0;           
         for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
         {
        if(i%num==0)
        {
        counter = counter + 1;
        }
     }
     if (counter ==2)
     {
        //Appended the Prime number to the String
        primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
     }  
      } 
      System.out.println("Prime numbers from m to n are :");
      System.out.println(primeNumbers);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing though. If you just give a solution out of the box, you haven't helped the OP actually figure out the problem with their code.